# when trying to reproduce a directed graph using amcharts I get error : "export 'default' (imported as 'am4plugins_forceDirected') was not found

Tags: angular, amcharts4

I am trying to reproduce a simple amcharts directed graph example using angular, but I am getting an error that I cannot seem to resolve. The error says "export 'default' (imported as 'am4plugins_forceDirected') was not found in '@amcharts/amcharts4/plugins/forceDirected'.

I reinstalled amcharts and checked out the file in question, it seems to be as it should. I replaced the whole amcharts folder anyway with the one found on their website and it did not solve the problem.

Here is what the code looks like :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
import am4themes_animated from "@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated";
import am4plugins_forceDirected from "@amcharts/amcharts4/plugins/forceDirected";

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph',
  templateUrl: './graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.css']
})

export class GraphComponent {
  private chart: am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);
      let networkSeries = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries());


    chart.data = [
      {
        name: "Core",
        children: [
          {
            name: "First",
            children: [
              { name: "A1", value: 100 },
              { name: "A2", value: 60 }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Second",
            children: [
              { name: "B1", value: 135 },
              { name: "B2", value: 98 }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Third",
            children: [
              {
                name: "C1",
                children: [
                  { name: "EE1", value: 130 },
                  { name: "EE2", value: 87 },
                  { name: "EE3", value: 55 }
                ]
              },
              { name: "C2", value: 148 },
              {
                name: "C3", children: [
                  { name: "CC1", value: 53 },
                  { name: "CC2", value: 30 }
                ]
              },
              { name: "C4", value: 26 }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Fourth",
            children: [
              { name: "D1", value: 415 },
              { name: "D2", value: 148 },
              { name: "D3", value: 89 }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Fifth",
            children: [
              {
                name: "E1",
                children: [
                  { name: "EE1", value: 33 },
                  { name: "EE2", value: 40 },
                  { name: "EE3", value: 89 }
                ]
              },
              {
                name: "E2",
                value: 148
              }
            ]
          }

        ]
      }
    ];

    networkSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
    networkSeries.dataFields.name = "name";
    networkSeries.dataFields.children = "children";
    networkSeries.nodes.template.tooltipText = "{name}:{value}";
    networkSeries.nodes.template.fillOpacity = 1;
    networkSeries.manyBodyStrength = -20;
    networkSeries.links.template.strength = 0.8;
    networkSeries.minRadius = am4core.percent(2);

    networkSeries.nodes.template.label.text = "{name}"
    networkSeries.fontSize = 10;

    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.dispose();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
```

It should show a simple directed graph but I get stuck at the point where I use the directed graph file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by the last import statement, it should be like this : import * as am4plugins_forceDirected from "@amcharts/amcharts4/plugins/forceDirected";
I was able to solve it thanks to martynasma from the amcharts' team github page!